# Endless files with copytruncate option in logrotate

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate, pm2

When I use logrotate with this configuration:

```
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/* {
        rotate 2
        size 200k
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        copytruncate
        create 0640 ubuntu ubuntu
}
```

My file (let's call it `test`) doesn't get rotated until it reaches 200k. Upon it reaching 200k it gets copytruncate-ed. I am left with `test` at 0k (correct!) and `test.1` at > 200k.

The problem is that the next day I shall get `test` > 0k (growing correctly), `test.1` at 0k and `test.1.1` at > 200k. As days progress, I will eventually get an endless number of `test.1.1.1.1...` at 0k with the last one at > 200k created yesterday.

My original idea was to have two files, `test` at whatever size less than 200k and another, older, log file only.

I need to use copytruncate as if I don't the PM2 process is going to keep writing to the old log file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody who stumbles on a similar issue.

The problem is in this line:

```
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/* {
```

In particular, the catch-all ***** should be swapped with ***.log**, or else, the rotated files (with extension .1, etc.) shall also be rotated upon the next rotation cycle.

This fixes the issue:

```
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/*.log {
```